# Wrong count execution times of Sinon Spy

Tags: javascript, chai, sinon, nock

I have a major function that call 3 other functions. I want to test if those 3 function were called.

#### myController.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';

export async function functionOne() {
  console.log('Hit functionOne');
  const result = await axios.get('https://www.urlOne.com/first');
  return result;
}

export async function functionTwo() {
  const result = await axios.get('https://www.urlTwo.com/second');
  return result;
}

export async function functionThree() {
  const result = await axios.get('https://www.urlThree.com/third');
  return result;
}

export async function mainFunction() {
  const resultOne = await functionOne();
  // some logic that also calls functionTwo & functionThree
}
```

#### test.spec.ts

```
import * as myCtrl from '../controllers';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(sinonChai);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

describe('success', () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

  // Create Spies
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox.spy(myCtrl, 'functionOne');
    sandbox.spy(myCtrl, 'functionTwo');
    sandbox.spy(myCtrl, 'functionThree');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  })


  it('test something', async () => {
    nock('https://www.urlOne.com')
      .get('first')
      .reply(200)

    nock('https://www.urlTwo.com')
      .get('second')
      .reply(200)

    nock('https://www.urlThree.com')
      .get('third')
      .reply(200)

    await myCtrl.mainFunction();

    expect(myCtrl.functionOne).to.be.calledOnce();
    expect(myCtrl.functionTwo).to.be.calledOnce();
    expect(myCtrl.functionThree).to.be.calledOnce();
  });
});
```

It looks weird, but according to the [nock documentation](https://github.com/nock/nock#read-this---about-interceptors), using multiple nocks is the right way.

Also tried using [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) instead of Nock, but the same error occurs.

The problem is, it always returns:

```
AssertionError: expected functionOne to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
```

I can see the `console.log` message on console, but the count still 0. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an **import scope** issue.

Stubbing or spying a module depends on export style. The mentioned case imports separate exports and assemble them into one.

```js
import * as myCtrl from '../controllers';
```

The problem is that `functionOne,two,three` in `mainFunction()` are different from the ones that you've imported and spied. **`sinon` can't expose and modify the function's inner scope. It can only modify what it can access.**

```
// for convenience, let's say
// functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree = f1,f2,f3

// controller.js
export function f1() {}
export function f2() {}
export function f3() {}
export function mainFunction() { f1(); f2(); f3() }

// spying(stubbing) in test
import { f1, f2, f3, mainFunction } from './controller';

// it does not wrap or modify mainFunction.f1()
// because,
// f1 !== mainFunction.f1
sinon.spy(f1)
```

## Solution

1. Just disconnect inner functions and separate the logic layer as a pure function. I personally like this approach because it's the simplest and less likely to cause dependency issues when testing.

```
// get the functions as arguments, so that you can test the pure logic
// controller.js
export function f1() {}
export function f2() {}
export function f3() {}
export function mainFunction(f1,f2,f3) { f1(); f2(); f3(); }

// test
import { mainFunction } from 'controller';
describe('', () => {
  let f1;
  // ...
  before(() => {
    // ...
    f1 = sinon.spy(require('controller').f1);
  })
  it('test', () => {
    mainFunction(f1, f2, f3);
    // check the spy from here
  })
})
```

2. separate functions into different modules then [stub a dependency of the module](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/)
3. make the module as a whole, and modify the specific property.

```
// controller
// it does not have to be a class. just make the inner functions to share the same scope.
class Controller {
  constructor() {}
  f1() {}
  f2() {}
  f3() {}
  mainFunction() {
    this.f1(); // ...implement logic here
  }
}

// test
import Controller from 'controller';

describe('', () => {
  let controller;

  before(() => {
    controller = new Controller();
    sinon.spy(controller.f1);
  })

  it('test', () => {
    controller.mainFunction()
    // check the spy from here
  })

})
```